# Blackberry Analytics - Adoption event

Tags: blackberry

I have included adoption events on button action in a mobile application. I am capturing the number of times a button is clicked in a given session and passing it as value in trackAdoptionEvent method. I don't see it captured in the analytics portal. Why is it not coming through the portal?

Comment: Please share the Analytics specific code where you are posting the event.  Do you see the application on the BlackBerry Analytics portal?

Comment: BAFBlackberryAnalytics.trackApplicationEvent(.adoptionEvent, withValue:String(BBAnalyticsAdoptionEventValues.clickCount) , forKey: "Key123") { (err) in
                    print(err as Any)
                }

Comment: Has the BlackBerry Analytics entitlement been assigned in BlackBerry UEM to the user you are testing with? It appears like it may not be.

Answer (score 0):

How long have you waited? It takes 24 hours for data to appear in the BlackBerry Analytics Portal.

Comment: am checking this after 24 hours only.. it is not captured anywhere in the portal.